# Does Java EE include Java SE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am following a tutorial about Java EE - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaff.html

and when I deploy the netbean project with netbean and the bundled glassfish, it return error saying it cannot find java persistence.

```
Compiling 11 source files to E:\Raymond\Programming Practice\j2ee\javaeetutorial5\examples\web\bookstore\build\classes
E:\Raymond\Programming Practice\j2ee\javaeetutorial5\examples\web\bookstore\src\com\sun\bookstore\database\Book.java:13: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
E:\Raymond\Programming Practice\j2ee\javaeetutorial5\examples\web\bookstore\src\com\sun\bookstore\database\Book.java:14: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

I realized that I might need to install java EE as I already have java SE6 in the machine.

But does Java EE include Java SE? I am trying not to create duplication.

If Java EE include Java SE, I would need to uninstall my Java SE then install the java EE.

If Java EE does not include Java SE, I should install Java EE seperately.

Comment: If you have Netbeans version with bundled Glassfish, it would have also included Java EE. I don't think you would need to install it seperately.

Answer (score 4):

Java EE is built on top of Java SE.  Yes, you have to install it separately.

If you have Java SE 6 on your machine already, then you have what you need.

The class cited in the exception is a Java EE class.  I'm guessing it means you've got a CLASSPATH issue.  Add the persistence.jar to your CLASSPATH.